# getting 401 while making soap call using karate

Tags: karate

By using karate framework I am able to make a rest call however I need to make a soap call in the same framework, when I do that I am getting 401 (unauthorized) response. I have "jks" file for that. Could any one help me to make a soap call with certificate using karate framework.

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try simply setting `* configure ssl = true` (and using HTTPS) as documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

If the `jks` file is really being validated by the server (mutual auth) try this. You need the latest (release candidate) version 0.7.0.RC6

`JKS` should work instead of `PKCS12` in the example below:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-demo/src/test/java/ssl/ssl-truststore.feature

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions.

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem and solicit opinions rather than facts." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I prefer to follow the rules and policies of Stack Overflow, as I linked for you, over your opinion.

Comment: He is asking for help writing a soap call. A direct violation of the rules and it will eventually be closed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Your opinion of how the rules should be applied does not matter.

Comment: I am writing hear to learn something, the way I wrote the query, may some one interpret like Rob I am sorry about that.

Comment: I followed the example, right now I am getting the error "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: request". I am using karate-core version 0.7.0.RC6. When I use version 0.6.1 I am getting cert error. Am I missing anything?

Comment: see my prev comment. also open a new question.